# Display menu on focus and hide when out of focus or clicked other than the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display menu (`#lorem-ipsum-wrapper`) when the div (`#content`) is focused, and again **hide the menu if neither the div or the menu is clicked**.

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('ready');

  $('#content').on("focus", function(event) {
    $('#lorem-ipsum-wrapper').css("display", "block");
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(document).on("click", function() {
    $('#lorem-ipsum-wrapper').css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

demo at [codepent.io](http://codepen.io/Kakar/pen/VvjjwM)

But the problem is that as soon as the `#content` is in focus, the menu displays and then again hides itself. Isn't the `stopPropagation()` method used to stop this? What am I doing wrong? Your help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: why dont use a css solution like #content:focus > #lorem-ipsum-wrapper ?

Comment: @Vanojx1 But what about if clicked on the menu?

Comment: The `document` also contains your `#content`, so the menu will be hidden if the user clicks on the `#contain`. To solve this, you can use onblur, the opposite of onfocus. Do a Google search on it.

Comment: @Arjun Onblur wont help because I don't want it to hide only on blur of the content but also if the menu is not clicked. If the menu is clicked, it will also make the menu to hide, which I don't want.

Comment: Then you can add the jquery's `:not`, it is used to do a specific operation on a group of elements but not on the elements passed to the `:not` method. So, use the `onblur` and also add a line `$(document:not('#content).click....`

Comment: I will check on it. Thank you. May be answering would be better though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help ?

```
 $(document).click(function(e) {
    var e = $(e.target), eid = e.attr("id");
    if (!e.parents("#lorem-ipsum-wrapper").length && !e.parents("#content-wrapper").length && eid !== "content-wrapper" && eid !== "lorem-ipsum-wrapper") {
      $('#lorem-ipsum-wrapper').css("display", "none");
    }
  });
```

or you can use blur event :

```
  $('#content').on("focus", function(event) {
    $('#lorem-ipsum-wrapper').css("display", "block");
  });

  $('#content').on("blur", function(event) {
     $('#lorem-ipsum-wrapper').css("display", "none");
  });
```

Comment: I only need the menu to hide when the menu is not clicked or the content is blur. In your case even if the menu is clicked it will hide the menu itself.

Comment: You just need to add id of the menu to the if condition > check edit

Comment: I tried your code, but its still not working. When I click the menu, it hides. Could you try in [codepen](http://codepen.io/Kakar/pen/VvjjwM).

Comment: check edit, now clicking anywhere in lorem ipsum menu or content input wont close your menu.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstand, you want to hide `#lorem-ipsum-wrapper` if `#content` is not clicked and show the `#lorem-ipsum-wrapper` on click of `#content`. Then, your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('ready');
   $('#lorem-ipsum-wrapper').css('display','none');

  $('#content').on("focus", function(event) {
    $('#lorem-ipsum-wrapper').css('display','block');
  });

  $('#content').on("blur", function() {
    $('#lorem-ipsum-wrapper').css("display", "none");
 });
  $('#lorem-ipsum-wrapper').on("click",function(){
    $(this).css("display","block");
});
```

**Explanation:**

*The third lines ensures that the `lorem-ipsum-wrapper` is not show before executing any code.*

*The fourth and fifth lines make the `#lorem-ipsum-wrapper` visible whenever the focus is on the `#content`.*

*The seventh and eighth lines make the `lorem-ipsum-wrapper` hidden whenever the users clicks somewhere else on the page or make the `#lorem-ipsum-wrapper` lose focus.*

Comment: Yes, but there's another thing, the menu should not hide when clicking on the `#lorem-ipsum-wrapper` (which is the menu itselft).